# Restrict a website by IP

Tags: php, .htaccess

So, this is the thing. I have 4 groups of users (A,B,C). The thing is the next:

- A user connects to the page.
- Check the IP in the database, if it's from A group, send A's website. If it's from B group, send B website and so on...
- The websites are static, but has JS, CSS and images asswell.

Ok, my first approach is create a simple index.php:

```
<?php
include_once '../php/.htDBconnection.php';

$group = MyDB::getGroupIp(getIp());

if($group != null)
{
        echo file_get_contents('./'.$group.'/index.html');
}
else
{
        echo "Not authorized!";
}
```

The problem is, shows the html but doesn't download the CSS/JS/Images content. What is the problem?

Comment: The problem is CSS , JS and Images are served directly by the web-server without any PHP being ran. Should probably read up on how to use `.htaccess` to do what you want. However then you have the problem of not being able to access the DB via `.htaccess`

Answer (score 1):

I think you could set the base-url (http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/html-base-element/) in your subpages to ensure the sub-page uses its own asset directory.